# oracle sql plus script is too long

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

```
select (select SUM(t.fees_amount)from unit u, payment p, type_of_fees t WHERE u.unit_id = p.unit_id AND p.stof = t.stof AND u.unit_id LIKE '%U1001%'
        AND p.stat = 'not payed') "BLOCK 1(Not Payed)",

        (select SUM(t.fees_amount)from unit u, payment p, type_of_fees t WHERE u.unit_id = p.unit_id AND p.stof = t.stof AND u.unit_id LIKE '%U1001%'
        AND p.stat = 'payed') "BLOCK 1(Payed)",

        (select SUM(t.fees_amount)from unit u, payment p, type_of_fees t WHERE u.unit_id = p.unit_id AND p.stof = t.stof AND u.unit_id LIKE '%U1002%'
        AND p.stat = 'not payed') "BLOCK 2(Not Payed)",

        (select SUM(t.fees_amount)from unit u, payment p, type_of_fees t WHERE u.unit_id = p.unit_id AND p.stof = t.stof AND u.unit_id LIKE '%U1002%'
        AND p.stat = 'payed') "BLOCK 2(Payed)"

from dual;
```

is there any other method to deal with this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation for this:

```
select sum(case when u.unit_id like '%U1001%' and p.stat = 'not payed' then t.fees_amount else 0 end) as "BLOCK 1(Not Payed)",
    sum(case when u.unit_id like '%U1001%' and p.stat = 'payed' then t.fees_amount else 0 end) as "BLOCK 1(Payed)",
    sum(case when u.unit_id like '%U1002%' and p.stat = 'not payed' then t.fees_amount else 0 end) as "BLOCK 2(Not Payed)",
    sum(case when u.unit_id like '%U1002%' and p.stat = 'payed' then t.fees_amount else 0 end) as "BLOCK 2(Payed)"
from unit u
join payment p on u.unit_id = p.unit_id
join type_of_fees t on p.stof = t.stof;
```

Also you should always use explicit join syntax instead of old comma based joins.

Comment: Is this because of my bad design for my database and lead to this long long script??

Comment: @user7868404 - I think it's the requirement. Since you must use `like`, the query can be slow. Although I've managed to put your four selects into one.